# How do I recover files from an USB flash drive?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, formatting, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flash drive ejected improperly- lost files](https://superuser.com/questions/89579/flash-drive-ejected-improperly-lost-files)

I have a USB flash drive that claims it needs to be formatted every time I put it into my computer (Windows).  Yesterday the drive was healthy and had data on it.  The data is probalby still there.  Are there any free tools to restore the drive?  If not free, what tools are known to work in this situation?