# ChipsBank Flash Disk - No Media (0 bytes of 0 bytes) after installing Arch Linux on Rufus

Tags: windows, usb, bios, rufus

It's a portable USB flash drive. I was trying to choose my USB flash drive as a bootable thing in BIOS settings, but did something wrong, and thought would be good idea to click in the BIOS "load default bios settings", and it somehow removed stuff from my USB flash drive completely.

I think it happened after I have loaded default BIOS settings, and my USB flash drive was plugged into my Lenovo Yoga L380. Please help, I have tried ApTool and such programs, but all I get is:

> UNKNOWN_FLASH,CE:0,ID:0000000000000000 Flash ID unknown.(0011)

- **Description**: [W:]USB Mass Storage Device(ChipsBnk Flash Disk)
- **Device Type**:  Mass Storage Device
- **Protocol Version**: USB 2.00
- **Current Speed:** High Speed
- **Max Current**: 100mA
- **USB Device ID**: VID = 1E3D PID = 198A
- **Device Revision**: 0100
- **Manufacturer**: ChipsBnk
- **Product Model**: Flash Disk
- **Product Revision**: 5.00
- **Controller Vendor**: ChipsBank
- **Controller Part-Number**: CBM2199E - [2019-11-11]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover files from an USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/89579/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: No, sadly it doesn't

Comment: Then, sorry to say, the USB flash drive is dead. UBS flash drives are considered commodity items and they tend to die fairly regularly. That is why they a recommended mainly for transporting files and not long term storage. If there is nothing of value on that drive, just toss it out an get a new one USB flash drive.

Comment: 1. Plug the USB drive into a different PC. 2. Use diskmgmt.msc, DidkGenius or other tool to remove *all* partitions. Commit. Create a new partition and format it appropriately. **If that does not work, the drive is dead.**