# broken usb memory stick< recover files

Tags: usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover files from an USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/51984/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive)

i have a usb memory stick that is not recognised in any computer, how do i recover the files so i can transfer them on to a new usb stick?

Answer (score 0):

When you say not recgonised, do you mean you get an error message popping up telling you there is a problem, or there is 0 activity whenever you plug this in?

Because with a bad file system, you have a chance, but with a dead key, you have no chance, unless you take it to a specialist.