# USB pen drive Defragmentation

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover files from an USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/51984/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive)

My friend got a HP 16GB USB pen drive. The problem is, he defragmented it. Now when we are connecting that device, its asking us to format it.

As it has very important information and can't be lost, is there any way to get that back? and how?

Pen Drive details: size 16GB, Filesystem: FAT32 (Not sure) but its now showing RAW.

Can anyone help on this. We use Windows OS (XP/ 7).

Comment: I wouldn't think its a duplicate. Here, the disk is defragmented and I still don't technically understand what makes a defragmented disk need to get formatted

Comment: Defragmenting it should not, in itself, result in loss of data. Note that if you have data that's very important, you should _never_ keep it in only one place.

Comment: Obvious question for recovery though - have you tried it in more than one computer?

Comment: Are you sure the drive isn't an el-cheapo-masquerading-as-high-capacity drive?

Comment: It doesn't help now and I'm sure the thought has now occurred to your friend but "very important information and can't be lost" really should mean copies are kept in at least three separate devices in at least two separate buildings. Backups!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest running [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and analyze partition table. Then you can try to restore it (it may corrupt your data).